# White corners in some GTK apps in ambiance theme

Tags: gtk3, calendar, ambiance

I am facing a problem with some certain apps i.e. 'gnome calendar', that  hard-edgy white corners are shown instead of the normal curved corners in the default ambiance theme

I am running a fully updated ubuntu 16.04 unity DE

I also don't want to switch into another theme

P.S this issue does not affect other themes like numix , arc , ...etc

[image]

Comment: Same problem here, I believe that it is a bug.

Comment: isn't it reported yet ?

Comment: I have really no idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with the calendar app itself. Ergo, we must wait for an upstream fix. Till then, "http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~willcooke/ubuntu-themes/ubuntu-themes-calendar-focus/revision/469".

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using **Gnome Shell** instead of Unitiy.

Ambiance (Radiance) theme has the same problem in Gnome Shell. But unlike Unity, **all** applications are rendered incorrectly, not only Gnome Calendar. The symptoms are the same: white (or black) top corners instead of transparent corners. Additionally, windows lack shadow.

I have managed to fix this by adding the following lines to **/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css** (or /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css for Radiance theme)

```
.window-frame {
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

First line (border-radius) fixes the issue with corners, and the second line (box-shadow) adds a shadow to windows.